# python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to learn django.I try to start the server by running

```
python manage.py runserver
```

but i get the following error

```
Django version 1.6.2, using settings 'coding.settings'
Starting development server at //127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", l
ine 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 187, i
n __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 47, in
 load_middleware
   mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 19,
in import_by_patherror_prefix, dotted_path))
ImproperlyConfigured: d doesn't look like a module path
```

please help me to remove this bug.

Comment: What middleware are you loading in the settings?

Comment: MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=(
    'django.middleware.common.commonMiddleware'
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware'
    
)

Comment: @user3500741 you don't have commas between middlewares, is it intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your configuration is incorrect:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.commonMiddleware'
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware'
)
```

There should be commas in between those middleware module paths:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.commonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

Without the commas, `('first' 'second' 'third')` in Python is the concatenated string value `'firstsecondthird'`.

When Django processes the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting, it iterates over its elements to load modules. If you separate the module paths by commas, then `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` is a tuple, and Django correctly loads each module. If you omit all the commas, then `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` is a  string, so iterating over that value will be iterating over the letters of the string. The first letter is `d`, so Django tries to load the path `d`, which of course "doesn't look like a module path".

Answer (score 4):

## It's in `settings.py`

Iv'e played with django's config - changed `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` from 2 backends into a single one

after a small debugging session iv'e discovered the solution

#### replace this representation:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
```

or

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
```

#### with this one:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
```